# SQL - Borrar registros que se obtienen por una subquery

Tags: mysql

Tengo dos tablas (no relacionadas) de un sistema muy viejo. Al querer relacionarlas se encuentran registros "huérfanos" sin su correspondiente padre. Los que no sirven, por lo que deben ser borrados.

```
SELECT * FROM movimiento m -- Los registros de esta tabla
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT NULL FROM expediente e -- Que no aparecen en esta tabla
                            WHERE e.clave_exp = m.clave_exp_mvto)
```

Esta consulta trae correctamente los registros (son cientos).
Quisiera saber cómo incluir una sentencia que me permita borrar este resultado SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toda vez que tu consulta (refieres) te devuelven los datos que se desean eliminar; una *opción* fácil es usar esa misma consulta usando solo la `PK` de la misma:

```
DELETE FROM movimiento
WHERE PK in (
    SELECT m.PK FROM movimiento m -- Los registros de esta tabla
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT NULL FROM expediente e -- Que no aparecen en esta tabla
            WHERE e.clave_exp = m.clave_exp_mvto
        )
)
```

> Hago uso de **PK** en referencia a la columna que es la LLave primaria y por consiguiente valor único en la tabla por cada fila. Sustituirla por el nombre de la columna respectiva.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

En relación a tu comentario; en tal caso crea una tabla temporal para guardar los IDs que se tendrán que eliminar:

```
-- Creamos la tabla temporal
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IdentificadoresABorrar [AS]  SELECT m.PK FROM movimiento m -- Los registros de esta tabla
        WHERE NOT EXISTS 
            (
                SELECT NULL FROM expediente e -- Que no aparecen en esta tabla
                WHERE e.clave_exp = m.clave_exp_mvto
            );

-- Procedemos a borrar 
DELETE FROM movimiento
    WHERE PK in (SELECT d.PK FROM IdentificadoresABorrar  d);

-- Eliminamos la tabla temporal
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IdentificadoresABorrar;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero da este error.

#1093 - Table 'movimiento' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data